# Does TK stand for anything?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers, empire, the-bad-batch

In the *Star Wars* universe, the Republic's troopers went by the designation "CT." The Empire's troopers started going by "TK" very early on, as seen in *The Bad Batch*. CT presumably, if not explicitly, stands for "Clone Trooper." Does TK stand for anything?

Comment: It stands for, "The license plate joke is getting old.  We should change 'THX' to something else."

Comment: Under the command of Tarkin (TK)?

Comment: @spacepheonix Maybe originally but apparently not anymore if so. It's used before he became a Grand Moff and after he died.

Comment: Perhaps “Troop K”. This Star Wars Fandom wiki page seems to indicate that the Empire switched from the “CT” designation to an alphanumeric operating number system that was more designed perhaps to designate the troop or battle group the individual belonged to rather than type of unit and also to distinguish officers from the soldiers. https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Operating_number

Comment: Yes, he stands for sentry duty and when an officer enters the room.

Answer (score -3):

Trooper Korps.

George Lucas took much from Germany in the creation of Star Wars, which would lead to the assumption of "Korps" rather than the more familiar "corps". This has not been directly clarified in canon, but it has not been contradicted either, and this idea comes from [The Galactic Senate](http://www.starwars.sg/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4134) and is the best I found in my research.